# Serial port - Getting unwanted values from Serial port using serialPort.readBytes(int values) in java

Tags: java, serial-port

I am getting unwanted values from Serial port using `serialPort.readBytes(int values)`.

```
serialPort.openPort();
serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0);
byte[] buffer = null;
buffer = serialPort.readBytes(20);

if (null != buffer) {
    String employee_id_var = "";
    String no = new String(buffer);
    no = no.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", ""); //removing garbage values comming from scaner serial input

    //for getting employee id
    if(no.length() > 6 && no.length() < 10){
        no = no.substring(0, 6);
        System.out.println("EMPLOYEE NO- "+no);
    }
}
```

I need clear string which has been scanned by scanner but here I am managing it by calling `no.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "")` for removing unwanted values.

It's not a feasible solution for my use case.
Can I get clear scanned data String from `serialPort.readBytes(20)`?

Comment: You need to explain what the format of the data coming from the scanner is, and why the solution you have implemented doesn't work.

Comment: Some times data coming from scanner is like 72A4G6  ^-!-^p*. so in this case p is not getting removed from string(by no.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "")) so the final output is like 72A4G6  p where 72A4G6 is my actual scanner result and 'p' is unwanted data.

Comment: Is there a CRC or checksum included in the data from the scanner? If not, then you are going to have a difficult time getting correct data if you are getting random characters from the scanner. If the bad characters are always a suffix to the correct data, perhaps you can use that fact. You need to explain more about the characteristics of the data and the noise. You also need to talk to the manufacturer of the scanner -- it may have a fault.

Comment: No, there is no CRC or checksum included in data from scanner. Can I use another methods(serialPort.readHexString(20) instead of serialPort.readBytes(20)) for getting scanner data for reducing noise or removing unwanted(Special Characters) data.

Comment: What do you know about the format of the data you are receiving? If it is a particular length then perhaps you can ignore trailing characters. If it is upper case only, then you can ignore lower case characters. But ulrimately you have defective hardware with no way to tell whether the data you receive is valid -- that cannot be fixed in software. Talk to your scanner vendor and get them to fix it.